# notification code for mouse over a tab item

Tags: c, winapi, tabs, tabitem

I have a tab control created by `CreateWindowEx(NULL, WC_TABCONTROL,...)`. I would like to have a notification when a mouse is over a tab item. The tab control has the style `TCS_TOOLTIPS` and when the mouse is over a tab item for an amount `TTDT_INITIAL` ms (whose default value is double click time), it will display a tooltip.

But I also need a notification immediately when a mouse is over a tab item. But I don't want to modify the `TTDT_INITIAL` value. In fact, when a mouse is over a non-selected tab item, it will change the color to blue by default. But I can not find the notification (and its receiver) for this thing.

So I would like to know if there is a way to `be notified immediately when a mouse is over a tab item` (winapi only).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no notification for that particular purpose.  The tabs are not their own controls, the entire TabControl as a whole is one control.  What you can do is have your window procedure for the TabControl catch `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages, and then call `TabCtrl_HitTest()` to determine which tab is currently underneath the mouse.  Keep track of the current tab so you can detect when the mouse moves across a tab boundary onto a new tab.